# Can I use a single URL to access Exchange online (office365)?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Currently in our EWS managed API we are using    "https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx".

My question is would this work with any customer setup? I read somewhere that above URL may have the company name part of it.

Comment: You should be using autodiscovery to find the right URL.  Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32355996/64161

Comment: @JakobChristensen Thanks, i have seen replies where it has been stated that autodiscoverUrl is not required and some MSDN references do not use it. SO should I be using this?

Comment: Yes I think you should. Then you will never have to worry about Microsoft changing the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

We have had no issues using that URL for all our customers.

It translates 'internally' (at the Exchange side) to something like `https://pod50446.outlook.com/ews/exchange.asmx` but you never have to deal with that.

Comment: Hi Jan, I tried Autodiscover and found the URL returned was the same outlook URL. Weird. Anyway, since AutoDiscover takes so long, we may just go with the outlook URL.